# MS Outlook: Calendar on right panel

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I'm using the "New Look" Outlook application and my Calendar pane has disappeared from the right side of the UI.  How do I get it back?

I've found a number of mentions of "To-do" being an option in the "View" ribbon ... but there is nothing in the view ribbon about making a panel on the right!  So those seem to refer to the old look Outlook.

What are the semantics and way to get this back in new Outlook?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The To-Do bar is not available in New Outlook for Windows. However, you can use a similar feature such as My Day to take a quick peek at your tasks and calendar events.

Select My Day My Day icon at the top of the page.

[image]

More information, see:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-my-day-in-outlook-1ca75cf8-6bfb-4ccb-8efc-7ee5831aef8d?ns=nwoutwin&version=90&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

Comment: Wasn't even the button I was pushing.  lol.   Honestly the "To Do" becoming "My Day" semantic change made this hard to google, so thanks for helping me fix that.

Answer (score 4):

In the new look Outlook, there's a button that appears upper right with the next meeting.   This button will launch a "My Day" view in a pane on the right.

If you clicked a specific meeting, you can use the back `<-` arrow to see the pane which allows a choice of To-Do and Calendar.

This pane seems otherwise absent from View ribbon, View settings, etc.  If you hit X to make the calendar/todo pane go away, you need to use the magic button to get it back.

... edited ...

@Faery's other answer points out that there are two "My Day" buttons:
[image: Outlook My Day To Do Buttons]

Hit the red-circled X, and it goes away.  Hit either green circled button and it comes back.

Note this is for "New Outlook" as indicated.